# Windows Shortcut Icon Issue

Tags: windows-7, icons, scaling

I created nice, large 512x512 ICO files for use as icons for my shortcuts. However, for some reason, when I scale them up some of them just do not scale. I've lived with it for 3 months, but, last night, many more suddenly began suffering from this issue. I have no idea what's causing it, but it's very annoying. I have tried renaming the icon files, but the issue still persists. It doesn't matter if I create new shortcuts or rename the ICO files, the problem still continues.

[image]

Here, Gotham City Imposters, Left 4 Dead 2, Super Hexagon, and Surgeon Simulator 2013 are exhibiting the issue (icons not scaling up) while Magicka, Natural Selection 2, Orcs Must Die! 2, Sanctum, Sanctum 2, Serious Sam 3: BFE, Team Fortress 2, and Trine 2 are working just fine.

Could anyone help me remedy this problem? I'd love for all my icons to be seen at full size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method One:

Try clearing your icon cache. Here's how to do it:

Source: [How to Rebuild the Icon Cache in Windows (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html)

> ### To Manually Rebuild the Icon Cache using the Command Prompt
>
> 1. Close and save anything that you are working on. This command will kill explorer and restart the computer when completed.
> 2. Open a command prompt in [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/947-command-prompt.html) or [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9702-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).
> 3. In the command prompt, Copy and paste each command line below exactly as is one at a time and press enter after each command.
>
>    **WARNING**: The last command will restart the computer, so be sure
>      to close and save anything that you are working on first.
>
>    - `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`
>    - `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`
>    - `DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A`
>    - `shutdown /r /f /t 00`
> 4. The **IconCache.db** file has now been rebuilt.
> 5. If the icons are still not displaying properly, then download and merge the ICO option in this tutorial for [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) or [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html) to restore the default associations of .ico (icon) files.

---

## Method Two:

Clear your thumbnail cache. Here's how to do it:

Source: [To Clear and Reset Thumbnail Cache using Disk Cleanup (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10797-thumbnail-cache-clear-reset.html)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10797-thumbnail-cache-clear-reset.html)

> 1. Open [Disk Cleanup](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/818-disk-cleanup-open-use.html).
> 2. Check the **Thumbnails** box, and click on **OK**.
>
>    [image: Disk Cleanup - Thumbnails]
> 3. Click on the **Delete Files** button.
>
>    [image: Disk Cleanup - Delete Files]
> 4. Disk Cleanup will now clear the thumbnail cache and close.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't help; in fact, now three more icons are stuck in the smaller view :(
Although one icon did work properly; it's at full size now (Gotham City Imposters)

Comment: @shravyanga - Updated my answer, hopefully it'll work for you.

Comment: Still isn't working :/ ah well. I'll just code an alternative.